# C# FindAll method: I am struggling with the syntax

Tags: c#

Firstly, thanks a ton to the StackOverflow community. I am new to C#, and this group has pulled me out of the fire many times!

Issue:  I am having a bit of trouble with the C# FindAll method. Specifically, I can't make it work, and I know it is me...

Stuff that works fine:

```
public class City
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Country {get;set;}
}

public List<City> GetCities()
{
   List<City> cities = new List<City>();
   cities.Add(new City() { Name = "Istanbul", Country = "Turkey" });
   // etc, add a bunch more cities, including multiple entries for 
   // some cities
   return cities;
}
```

**Now what doesn't work...** (It returns all the cities or none (depending on how I fiddle the syntax).

```
public static List<> ReturnCityList(string CityName)
{
  Cities = GetCities;
  var RequestedCities = Cities.Findall(s => Name.Equals(CityName));
  return RequestedCities
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

I have read a lot of examples, but am missing something.

Thank you!

Comment: FYI: you don't need `Equals` for strings, the `==` operator is overloaded.

Comment: I think, it should be s => s.Name....
also GetCities should be static in this case, isn't it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var RequestedCities = Cities.Findall(s => Name.Equals(CityName));
```

Where is `Name` coming from?  Did you mean this?

```
var RequestedCities = Cities.Findall(s => s.Name.Equals(CityName));
```

Or even

```
var RequestedCities = Cities.Findall(s => s.Name == CityName);
```

Which does the same thing with a simpler syntax.

You aren't using the `s` variable, i.e., the variable that holds the current element in the iteration.  That's what you likely need to check against `CityName`.  I doubt your version even compiles.  Also...

```
public static List<> ReturnCityList(string CityName)
```

That won't compile.  You can't use an empty generic argument, you need to specify the return value as `List<City>` and then you will need to call `ToList()` on the result of the query. There are a couple other errors as well.

Honestly you should probably just return an `IEnumurable<City>` as the caller probably doesn't need to modify the return value, just enumerate it.

One more nitpick; method arguments use `camelCase` by convention, not `PascalCase`, as do local variables.

Comment: Thanks! I used "var RequestedCities = Cities.Findall(s => s.Name == CityName);" and that was exactly the ticket. Thanks also for the other tips!

Answer (score 4):

`Name` should be `s.Name`. (And there's no semicolon after the `return`, and `FindAll`'s capitalization is incorrect.) You can also just turn this into one line. So like this:

```
public static List<City> ReturnCityList(string CityName) {
    return GetCities.FindAll(s => s.Name == CityName).ToList();
}
```